# Dynamodb global secondary index not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a global secondary index in my dynamo db table as shown in the below screenshot -

[dynamodb GSI creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfsfM.png)

But when I am filtering data using this GSI it is not fetching any data as shown in the below screenshot -

[dynamodb query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqJY5.png)

I have also placed a screenshot of the sample data below -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65U9v.png)

Comment: can you do a screenshot of a data sample also?

Comment: Does the key admin_id with the value of 24 exist?

Comment: @hephalump yes it does exist

Comment: Please show it as @HoratiuJeflea requested

Comment: @hephalump I have edited the question and placed it there.

Comment: @hephalump If I am entering new record in the table then it is fetched successfully... that means old data is not indexed yet... what say?

Comment: Thanks. In your GSI that you created its a string, but it looks like admin_id is a number.

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: @hephalump  I have again created the index with number type... it is taking too much time... let's c  what happen!

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: It is still creating the index :)

Comment: @hephalump it has worked ... thanks a lot bro... u r a legend :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was a stupid mistake of mine. In my GSI that I have created is a string, but  admin_id is a number.